# awk doesn't recognize field as a number

Tags: text-processing, awk, locale

I think it's somewhat a simple problem but I don't understand what's happening.
I have a file such as

```
Scaffold_19:10402053-10402986   Scaffold_33:25064012-25064819   92.806  278 5   5   8   279 269 1   2.84e-107   388
Scaffold_6:54625155-54625833    Scaffold_33:6634011-6634353 96.774  248 6   2   1   248 97  342 1.21e-114   412
Scaffold_9:94800251-94801152    Scaffold_26:56326990-56327448   100.000 297 0   0   1   297 162 458 1.19e-155   549
Scaffold_20:79074547-79075122   Scaffold_20:79075175-79076351   93.269  208 11  3   1   208 972 1176    6.43e-82    303
Scaffold_18:6685836-6686898 Scaffold_19:81178714-81179662   99.789  949 1   1   114 1062    1   948 0.0 1740
Scaffold_18:46725018-46726185   Scaffold_18:46723864-46724938   84.309  752 73  29  1   710 323 1071    0.0 693
Scaffold_9:97974338-97975523    Scaffold_9:97976642-97978267    90.239  1045    81  18  155 1185    1   1038    0.0 1345
Scaffold_16:35667544-35671350   Scaffold_34:16160847-16161438   99.459  185 0   1   1   184 185 1   1.56e-90    335
Scaffold_33:47202231-47202984   Scaffold_33:47205382-47206652   94.763  611 31  1   3   613 642 1251    0.0 950
Scaffold_8:18583199-18586799    Scaffold_25:14231844-14235013   98.460  3116    43  3   1   3112    55  3169    0.0 5483
```

Now, all I want to do is to print the lines where the thirds column is <= to a number. That should be easy right? For example, print the lines where $3 is <= 100

```
head q.filtered.noself.blastn|awk '$3 <= 100'
```

But it returns nothing! Can you help? It's like awk doesn't recognize the third field is a number.

I am using mawk 1.3.4 20200120 on Ubuntu 20.04.2

here is a sample of the file
[sample](https://we.tl/t-JCkToJJ1y0)

EDIT: here is the output of locale

```
locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_GB:en
LC_CTYPE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_GB.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=fr_BE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Please [edit] your question and add i) your operating system (I see you tagged as Linux, but please add it to the question body and tell us which Linux), ii) your version/flavor of awk (see `awk -V`) and iii) upload a sample of the actual file somewhere and link us to it. Maybe there are non-printing characters in there confusing things.

Comment: Which implementation of `awk` are you using? POSIX-compliant implementations are required to use the decimal separator defined in your locale when parsing input data, which may not be the dot (`.`). GNU `awk` uses the dot by default for that, unless told not to. (And what is the output of `locale` in the environment you are running `awk` in?)

Comment: Yes, good point. Please also add the output of `locale`.

Comment: OK, try `head q.filtered.noself.blastn | LC_ALL=C awk '$3 <= 100'`

Comment: You may replace . with , in the third field to honor your locale. Use the gsub function. For example : { gsub("\.",",",$3); }

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that you have `LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8`. Under this locale, the decimal separator is `,` and not `.` so `98.9` is not considered a number. To illustrate:

```
$ echo "98.5" | LC_NUMERIC=C mawk '$1<100' 
98.5
$ echo "98.5" | LC_NUMERIC=fr_BE.UTF-8 mawk '$1<100' 
$
```

So either change your locale to one that has `.` as the decimal separator, or set the locale explicitly for this command:

```
head q.filtered.noself.blastn | LC_NUMERIC=C awk '$3 <= 100'
```

Comment: Hello, yes that was the problem. Thanks a lot!

Comment: that also seems to depend on the version of awk. I can't reproduce that with mawk 1.3.3, while 1.3.4 does indeed exhibit that. And GNU awk ignores what the locale says, unless you use `--use-lc-numeric` to say you want that.

Comment: @ilkkachu huh. I tested it with 1.3.4, that's the only one I have accessible.

Comment: either that or there's some difference in the locales between the two systems I tried on